# PublishState enum for Rendering Phase?

Tags: core-service, publishing

What is the Enum int for the Rendering Phase of a Publish Transaction?

I found [this handy chart about Publish States](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-714ACA0C-264F-4C63-8C93-AFFDA95C3DA3), but I don't think I understand where 'Rendering' is in the list.

In my code I have this list, but I forgot where I found it...and it seems to not correspond with the documented list above...

```
// 0 = Failed
// 1 = Scheduled for Publish
// 2 = Waiting for publish
// 3 = In progress
// 4 = Scheduled for deployment
// 5 = Waiting for deployment
// 6 = Failed
// 7 = Success
// 8 = Warning
// 9 = Resolving
// 10 = Rendering
// 11 = Throttled
// 12 = Ready for transport
// 13 = Transporting
// 14 = Deploying
// 15 = Preparing Deployment
// 16 = Pre-committing deployment
// 17 = Committing deployment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 9. The list in your code does not look quite right.

The TOM.NET and Core Service API documentation lists them as follows:

[image]

Up to and including 7 (`Warning`) these also match the old TOM's `TDSDefines.EnumPublishTransactionState`.

Of course... It's an enumeration, so you really shouldn't need to know what the number is, you should just be able to use `PublishTransactionState.Rendering`, which is far more readable and maintainable ;)

Comment: Love the 2 items for Success, 1 with a typo :)

Comment: Yeah. Only the typo existed until it was corrected in SDL Tridion 2011, but the typo had to stay in order to be backwards compatible. Both enumerate to 6 though, so are interchangeable. 'Succes' is marked as obsolete.